# Service reference, set generated propertyname if multiple

Tags: c#, .net

The targeted service reference has the following schema:

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="option1" type="tns:ctpObj1"/>
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="option2" type="tns:ctpOjb2"/>
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="option3" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
</xs:choice>
```

In the generated reference file it creates the following propery:

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("option1", typeof(ctpObj1), Order=4)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("option2", typeof(ctpObj1), Order=4)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("option3", typeof(string), DataType="nonNegativeInteger", Order=4)]
    public object Item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }
```

When sending the results, the property is now always called 'Item', this is incorrect, it should be option 1/2/3. Is there a way to specify the name without changing the generated reference file?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this (you could map the whole thing to a dynamically created class, but that is not easy or usually workable). Why not simply check the type of `Item` when you need to use it and cast it accordingly? If you want three different items, two of which are always null, you should change the service definition.

Comment: The problem is that we do not own the definition, so changing that is not that simple, same goes for checking the type. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Why is checking the type not simple when you don't own the definition?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you correctly. In code i just assign a string value to Item (option 3) and send the results. Where do i put the type check?